# Half of an Ellipsoid

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Why is this showing fuzzy?  Like the corona of a sun?

I want to graph the half of an ellipsoid 4x^2+y^2+4z^2=4 that lies to the right of the xz-plane.  I specifically want to show that it is half (the other half should show void space).

```
    ContourPlot3D [y == Sqrt[4 - 4 x^2 - 4 z^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}, All}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
ContourPlot3D[
 4 x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2 == 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
 PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}, All},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1},
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Another possibility is `ParametricPlot3D` with `ClipPlanes`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Sin[u] Sin[v], 2 Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}],
 ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 PlotStyle -> Darker @ Green,
 Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I just got something similar too by not using the square root version of the function.  So why did the square root produce something fuzzy?

Comment: You can also take `Sqrt[4 x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2] == 2`. The problem of your fuzzy plot was that you wrote 'y == ...' instead of `2 == ...'.

Answer (score 4):

You could show an [`Ellipsoid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html) object clipped with a [`ClipPlanes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) setting:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[ColorData[112, 2], ColorData[112, 3]], 
  Style[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}], ClipPlanes -> {0, 1, 0, 0}]}]
```

[image]